# hide iframe until link is clicked then hide link after link is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have this code to open link in iframe

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/" target="iframe1">link</a>

</br></br>

<iframe id="iframe1" name="iframe1" src="#"></iframe>
```

I want to hide iframe until link is clicked then hide link after link is clicked

I need to do that with javascript / jQuery

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do the following:

```
<div id="linkDiv">
    <a href="#" id="theLink">Link</a>
</div>
<br/><br/>
<iframe id="iframe1" name="iframe1" src="#"></iframe>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#iframe1").hide();
    $("#theLink").click(function(){
        $("#iframe1").show();
        $("#linkDiv").hide();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Put the link in Span tags and do the following:

```
$("#link").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    //Assuming you're assigning the source dynamically, if not, comment out below line.
    $("#iframe1").attr("src", $("link").attr("value");
    $("#iframe1").show();

    $("#linkBeGone").hide();
});
```

Make the href attrib of the link "#" and make the value the src you want the iFrame to be.

```
<span id="linkBeGone"><a id="link" value="http://www.example.com/" href="#" target="iframe1">link</a></span>

</br></br>

<iframe id="iframe1" name="iframe1" src="#"></iframe>
```